# How do I use an existing pickle file I have made in Thonny?

Tags: python, pickle, thonny

I am trying to use a pickle file that I receive from a friend and use it but every time I do load it I always get the the error "ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'const ITYPE_t' but got 'long long'".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyzxo.png)

Comment: What is the code that was used to save the model?

Comment: its an exiting pickle file given to me. I think he used
import pickle
filename = "Sample_model.pkl"
pickle.dump(rf, open(filename, "wb"))
to create it
 pickle.dump(rf, open(filename, "wb"))